# Pigeonhole principle, Euclidean Distance and Combinatorics

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Be [0,1] the intervall of all real numbers with 0 ≤ r ≤ 1.
So [0, 1] × [0, 1] is the unit square in the euklid plane. Now we have to show that if we pick any **10** points out of [0, 1] × [0, 1] (our unit square), that there are at least 2 different points that are less than $\frac{12}{25} = 0,48$ euclidean distance away from each other.

Our tutor explained it has to do with the Pigeonhole principle and (simple) combinatorics. What my interpretation of that is: If there are 9 Pigeon holes (9 places on the square, where the Euclidean distance is $\ge$ 0,48 (the special property [for the combinatorics]) , and we have to place another Pigeon (Circle) into the 9 Pigeon holes, then we will have 2 Pigeons (Circles) in the same Pigeon hole (in an euclidean distance of $\frac{12}{25}$).

I don't know how to formulate this into mathematics, and proof it "by manipulating numbers" I can only visualize this by the following picture.

I hope you can give me hints, so I can find the solution by myself. I don't want solutions as I really want to learn this. Thanks in advance!

[image: 9 Red Circles, 1 Green Circle; Diameters: 960px; Square 1000px*1000px]
Euclid plane: Blue square 1000px
Red Circles: 9 Circles, diameter 960px = 480*2 px
Green Circle: 1 Circle, diameter 960px

Comment: Divide the square in nine smaller ones ($3\times 3$).

Comment: Thanks, this was sufficient enough for me to prove it. I may post the answer